# How do I subscribe to OpenLayers 5.3.0 events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers, openlayers-5

I see that OpenLayers 5.3.0 is making use of observables. The docs also [cover events](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_events_Event-Event.html).

How would I alter this starting example to .subscribe() to events in general? I'm struggling bridging the gap between docs and use.

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new XYZ({
        url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

I've [seen examples](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/feature-events.js) with older versions of OpenLayers that may not apply here. At least in the linked example above, "eventListeners" is not listed as a property on 5.3.0 and seems old and callback-related (not observable).

I did see a more recent, similar question [here with helpful resources listed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252946/what-are-the-possible-listeners-and-event-types-for-an-openlayers-map-ol-map). I could use a script example to help get started.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/moveend.html ?

Comment: Aha! Yes. That was simple. Thanks for locating that example. If you put that in an answer, it gets the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register events, for example on the map. In the [latest examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples) there is an example for the [moveend event](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/moveend.html).

```
var map = new Map({
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});

map.on('moveend', function(evt){console.log(evt);});
```